# streaming multiple log4net logs to elasticsearch via UDP ports

Tags: elasticsearch, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

How can I stream logs from multiple log4net in elasticsearch??
For example, if I have multiple Windows servers with .net apps and log4net running on each server, each server streaming logs on a separate UDP port.  How do I setup logs on elasticsearch server to index logs from multiple ports ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use logstash connectors for this purpose. Look at this :
[Using logstash, ElasticSearch and log4net for centralized logging in Windows](http://www.ben-morris.com/using-logstash-elasticsearch-and-log4net-for-centralized-logging-in-windows/)